# Wordpress - loop image description

Tags: php, wordpress

```
  function the_post_thumbnail_caption() {
  global $post;
  $thumbnail_id    = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
  $thumbnail_image = get_posts(array('p' => $thumbnail_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment'));


  if ($thumbnail_image && isset($thumbnail_image[0])) {
    echo '<p>'.$thumbnail_image[0]->post_content.'</p>';
  }
 }
```

I've seen this code in the net. But it only displays the first image description that has been attached. I'm new in wordpress and still getting problems with coding. How can I put this inside a loop for it to display all the image description that has been attached. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
     function the_post_thumbnail_caption() {
        global $post;
        $childs = get_children(array('post_parent' => $post->ID));
        if($childs) {
         foreach($childs as $child) {
         echo '<p>'.$child->post_content.'</p>';
         }
        }
      }
?>
```